# How can I know whch web site loads my image?

Tags: php

I have created some free HTML Templates, to share them for free, but I would like to know where my  templates are installed.

What I have in my mind, in order to track the template installation, is to create a php script that will generate a single pixel image. I would like to use that image to collect information about the web site that loads my picture.

So, how can I know which server is requesting my image? Any ideas?

Comment: See if this help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously whatever you do could be stripped out, since once your template code is obtained the user could just delete the reference to track back to your script.

A pixel loading off of your server would work, you could access the data within $_SERVER to find out some information about the request and look for a referrer.

A better idea, IMO, is to write some javascript code that lives on your server and is included via a `<script src="..."></script>` tag on your template.  This would allow you to "phone home" by dynamically creating an image source tag to fire this pixel off to your server with more information about the source.

For example, you could so something as simple as this:

```
(function()
{
    var img = document.createElement('img'),
    src = "//www.yourserver.com/path/to/pixel.php?domain=" + document.domain;

    img.src = src;
})();
```

This would fire a pixel to your server and contain the domain that loaded your template.  You could add a bunch more code that identifies the browser, uniquely tracks the user - see what kind of traffic the site is getting, whatever.

Be sure you don't use any 3rd party JS libraries, as you don't want to inject dependencies/increase load time on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Or if you need something else, try here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: You could use HTTP_HOST, but it'd have to be from the TEMPLATE side of the transaction, so like: `<img src="//yourserver.com/pixel.php?host=<?= urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); ?>">`.

Comment: not necesarily. You can do it like this : `<img src="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']";?>/<?=$path_to_template;?>/<?=$path_to_image;?>`" />.

Comment: HTTP_HOST points to the server serving the request; so, while your code would work - it's unnecessary.  Also, requesting the image from the local template doesn't really accomplish much - the goal is to have the template "phone home" to the author, so he can see who's using it

Answer (score 2):

When you generate your single pixel image, include information that you're interested in such as this. Then check your server logs.

```
echo '<img src="onepixel.png?servedby='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].">';
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, `REMOTE_ADDR` is the user's IP address.  If this was injected into the template, it would just tell him the user's IP address that requested the image; which he wouldn't need because he'd get that at the time of the request anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, but "such as this" was the operative, so whatever information is of interest can be captured this way.